# Xamarin.Forms (Android): Add Bottom Border to Navigation Bar

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I would like to add a bottom border to the navigation bar in Xamarin Forms on Android.

On iOS I already wrote a custom renderer:

```
public class CustomNavigationBarRenderer : NavigationRenderer
{
    private static readonly string ColorCode = "03d79e";
    private static readonly Lazy<UIImage> BorderBottomLine = new Lazy<UIImage>(GetPixelImage);
    
    protected override void OnElementChanged(VisualElementChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (Element == null)
            return;
        NavigationBar.ShadowImage = BorderBottomLine.Value;
    }

    private static UIImage GetPixelImage()
    {
        UIGraphics.BeginImageContext(new CGSize(1, 1));
        CGContext context = UIGraphics.GetCurrentContext();
        context.SetFillColor(Color.FromHex(ColorCode).ToCGColor());
        context.FillRect(new CGRect(0, 0, 1, 1));
        UIImage image = UIGraphics.GetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphics.EndImageContext();
        return image;
    }
}
```

Unfortunately it's not that simple on Android, or at least I haven't figured it out yet.

Is there any simple way to implement a bottom border on the navigation bar?

[image: Navigation Bar Border Bottom]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NavigationPage.TitleView` does not help , because its width does not fill with Navigationbar(has space on left side) and what's more important is that it only represents the content inside Navigationbar(but we want border) .

See the test below

```
<NavigationPage.TitleView>

    <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Spacing="0" Margin="0" Padding="0">
        <Frame BackgroundColor="Red" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
    </StackLayout>
</NavigationPage.TitleView>
```

[image]

---

To implement the bottom border  android, you could create a shape with a xml file , and set the background on Toolbar .

1. Create a file named `line.xml` in folder `Resources/drawable` and copy the following code into it .

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <item>
       <shape>
         <solid android:color="#06D1A7" />
       </shape>
     </item>
     <item android:bottom="4dp">
       <shape>
         <solid android:color="#221E4E" />   
       </shape>
     </item>
   </layer-list>
   ```
2. Set Background on `Toolbar.xml`

   ```
   android:background="@drawable/line"
   ```

[image]

---

PS : I tried to implement in custom renderer but no luck ,maybe someone could provide the solution in this way .

Comment: Hi, does my solution help or not ?

Comment: Hi ColeX, thanks for your answer, yes, the drawable solutions works!

Comment: @ColeX-MSFT hey colex where is that toolbar.xml? Im using xamarin forms and navigation drawer and want to implement the same thing but wher should I pass the line.xml? I have the navigation.title on my project

Comment: @AlexRika in android project .

Answer (score 2):

To make it very simple you can use the `NavigationPage.TitleView` to customize your Header. Refer to the [documentation here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/hierarchical#displaying-views-in-the-navigation-bar) for more details.

If that does not work out for you, then the solution would be to write a CustomRender for your NavigationBar extending from `NavigationPageRenderer`.

Please [refer to the post here](https://www.xamboy.com/2017/12/06/navigation-bar-customization-in-xamarin-forms/) which has some amazing content about customizing the NavigationBar.

Answer (score 0):

I realized it the following way:

Create a file called "custom_background_bar.xml" in the drawable folder in your Android project.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <solid android:color="#ff292550" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:top="-3dp" android:right="-3dp" android:left="-3dp">
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
            <stroke
                    android:width="2dp"
                    android:color="#ff03d79e" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

The go to to the Resources/layout/Toolbar.axml file and set the following:

```
android:background="@drawable/custom_background_bar"
```

After that the background is set. You just should not set the BarBackgroundColor in your Xamarin.Forms project.

You could also create a custom Renderer that sets the Background property to `Context.GetDrawable(Resource.Drawable.custom_background_bar)`

Hint: Same works with the BottomNavigationView, if you want a top border, just use android:bottom="-3dp" instead of android:top="-3dp"